# Ajax page fade and change navigation background color

Tags: jquery, ajax

I want to change the background color of my navigation when I click from home to about for example.

You can see a example on this page look at the Navigation: [EXAMPLE](http://hellomonday.com)

Even from actually color X to Y.

This is the sequence:

1. When a navigation button is clicked...
2. Change the hash tag of the URL
3. When the hash tag in the URL changes...
4. Fade out the old content
5. Load and fade in the new content
6. Update the current navigation highlighting and change navigation background color

   ```
   $(function() {

   var newHash      = "",
   $mainContent = $("#main-content"),
   $pageWrap    = $("#page-wrap"),
   baseHeight   = 0,
   $el;

   $pageWrap.height($pageWrap.height());
   baseHeight = $pageWrap.height() - $mainContent.height();

   $("nav").delegate("a", "click", function() {
   window.location.hash = $(this).attr("href");
   return false;
   });

   $(window).bind('hashchange', function(){

   newHash = window.location.hash.substring(1);

   if (newHash) {
       $mainContent
           .find("#guts")
           .fadeOut(200, function() {
               $mainContent.hide().load(newHash + " #guts", function() {
                   $mainContent.fadeIn(200, function() {
                       $pageWrap.animate({
                           height: baseHeight + $mainContent.height() + "px"
                       });
                   });
                   $("nav a").removeClass("current");
                   $("nav a[href='"+newHash+"']").addClass("current");
               });
           });
   };

   });

   $(window).trigger('hashchange');

   });
   ```

Comment: where is the question? where is the color animation code you have so far?

Comment: @Alex i don't know how to solve it.. is that even easy possible? :D

Comment: @Alex because the actually color X must be variable from the css? or not?